# Help using /fill command with NBT tags on spawners in 1.14

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a mob grinder, and have some spawners I need to place. However, I'd like the player diatance tag to be 1000, instead of the usual 16.

I know it should look something like this:

```
/fill 5527 187 1981 5516 187 1997 minecraft:spawner replace air {RequiredPlayerRange:1000}
```

Honestly, I'm not quite sure how to go about this. Do I have to do it individually for each spawner with this?

```
/data merge block ~ ~-1 ~ {RequiredPlayerRange:1000}
```

Comment: You could completely overwrite all spawners in the range, but if you want to just change this one propertly of them, then yes, you need to do it one by one.

Answer (score 1):

It took some testing, but this seems to work:

```
/fill 5527 187 1981 5516 187 1997 minecraft:spawner{MaxNearbyEntities:6,RequiredPlayerRange:1000} replace air
```

Comment: I am not sure why, but MaxNearbyEntities seems to be required for RequiredPlayerRange to get set with this command. Does anyone know why?